# ¿Cómo pasar un valor a la view desde el controller en .NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Tengo el siguiente `Controller` y `View`:

**CONTROLLER**

```
[httpPost]
public actionResult metodo()
{
  viewBag.valor = true;
 return RedirectToAction("modificar");
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@{
if(viewBag.valor)
//hacer algo.
}
```

El problema acá es que la propiedad "**valor**" del `viewBag` siempre me viene en `null`. por mas que si se este pasando por el método del `controller`.

¿Porque?
muchas gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Hay un poco de confusión de concepto. 
En tu caso, para que el valor sea leído en tu action luego del redireccionamiento, tienes que usar TempData y no ViewBag, ya que los valores de ViewBag se están eliminando luego de enviar la respuesta al cliente como parte del Redirect (método RedirectToAction).

Prueba este código:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    TempData["Valor"] = true;
    return RedirectToAction("Modificar");
}

public ActionResult Modificar() {
    var valor = TempData["Valor"] as bool?;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Valor:{valor}");
    return View();
}
```

Para leer desde tu vista Modificar.cshtml:

```
<body>
<div> Hola </div>
<div>@ViewBag.Valor</div>
<div>@TempData["Valor"]</div>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para mantener valores entre métodos de acción (Action Methods) puedes utilizar el diccionario TempData

```
TempData["valor"] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

El `ViewBag` no es trasferible a otra vista cuando se efectua una redireccion por lo que no puedes redireccionar a otra vista y esperar poder acceder a los `ViewBag`s del action anterior.

O creas el `ViewBag` en la vista final o envías el parametro por la url asi:

```
return RedirectToAction("modificar", new { valor  = true});
```

Entonces en tu vista utilizas `Request` en vez de `ViewBag`:

```
@{
  if(Request["valor"] == "true")
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: No había entendido bien tu respuesta y por eso te puse -1. Edita algo para que pueda deshacer el downvote ;)